# How to refactor my angularjs function with if validations and 2 foreach loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, if-statement, foreach

I've written this function in order to loop through some files and their children items depending on certain criteria. Depending on what the criteria is for the file, it will return true or false.

I've made a variable validFile to keep track of the return value.

I feel like there is a cleaner way to make the function more fluid....if someone can give me some pointers on how i can make this function more simple that'd be great.

```
function checkFile() {
    // track file validity value
    var validFile;

    // check to see if files exists
    if($scope.files.length) {
      angular.forEach($scope.files, function(file) {
         // check to see that file has a child item
         if(file.item && file.item.child.length > 1) {
          angular.forEach(file.item.child, function(item) { 
            if(item.child.code === 8) {
              validFile = true;
            }
          });
        } else {
          validFile = false;
        }

      });
    } else {
      validFile = false;
    }

    return validFile;
  }
```

PS. the function works fine....just want to clean it up and refactor it to be neater

EDIT:

example of files goes something like this...

```
 $scope.files = [{
      length: 1,
      type: pdf,
      item: {
        child:[{
           type: pdf,
           code: 8
        }]
      }
    }]
```

The validFile will be true if

- $scope.files and file.item.child exists
- item.child.code has a value of 8

thanks

Comment: Can you provide some sample dummy data for **$scope.files** to have idea how it looks?

Comment: Please further explain what determines if the file is valid or not.

Comment: I don't think you'd have a length attribute for $scope.files are shown above.

Comment: You are looping over `file.item.child` - but your example shows it as an object, not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following refactoring:

```
  function checkFile() {
    var result = false;
    if(angular.isArray($scope.files)) {
      angular.forEach($scope.files, function(file) {
         if(file.item && angular.isArray(file.item.child)) {
          angular.forEach(file.item.child, function(child) { 
            if(child.code === 8) {
              result = true;
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Main things that I did:

- checking for an array of top-level object is switched to `angular.isArray`;
- `file.item.child.length` could be 1;
- inner loop is protected by `angular.isArray` condition;
- inner loop iteration variable is `child`, not `item`;
- also I generalized the `result` flag with `false` as initial value.

Furhter refactoring could contain following ideas:

- replace `forEach` logic with breakabe logic (plain old for-loop or `Array.prototype.some` or something else) to reduce iterations amount...

Answer (score 0):

The function name is a bit of a misnomer, since you're checking *files* not a single file. Break it out then call your function in a loop.

You can also remove a few lines by just initially setting `validFile` to false.

```
function checkFile(file) {
  var validFile = false;
  if(file.item && file.item.child.length > 1) {
    angular.forEach(file.item.child, function(item) { 
      if(item.child.code === 8) {
        validFile = true;
      }
    });
  }
  return validFile;
}

angular.forEach($scope.files, checkFile); // ok to have length of 0
```